# How to render highcharts from external json for multiple series

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, ajax, highcharts

I am using angularjs and highcharts having multiple series,data is coming from external json. when I using hardcoded value data.data[0].data,its  working fine but if I use data.data[i].data with for loop its not working.Can any one please help me.Here is the code below. https://plnkr.co/edit/NPmG56Xd7TuYohRH2lZJ?p=preview

### html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

### script

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
  $http({
    method: "get",
    url: "chart.json",
    // headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
  }).
  then(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data.data[0].data;
    console.log($scope.data);
    Highcharts.chart('container', {

      title: {
        text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
      },

      subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
      },

      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
      },

      series: [{
        data: $scope.data
      }],
    });
  })    
});
```

### chart.json

```
[{
    "name": "Installation",
    "data": [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
}, {
    "name": "Manufacturing",
    "data": [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working code for multiple series, there was the issue in an assignment

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
  $http({
    method: "get",
    url: "chart.json",
    // headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
  }).
  then(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data.data;
    Highcharts.chart('container', {

      title: {
        text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
      },

      subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
      },

      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
      },

      series: $scope.data,



    });
  })

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div id="container"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

> Assignment of data change
>    **$scope.data = data.data[0].data;**

Changed to

> **$scope.data = data.data;**

Assign series to chart

> **series: $scope.data**